# Comparing wait-signal alternatives for synchronizing two piece of programs

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, deadlocks, mutual-exclusion, semaphore

I came across following problem:

> A certain computation generates two arrays `a` and `b` such that `a[i]=f(i)` for `0 ≤ i < n` and `b[i]=g(a[i])` for `0 ≤ i < n`. Suppose this computation is decomposed into two concurrent processes X and Y such that X computes the array `a` and Y computes the array `b`. The processes employ two binary semaphores `R` and `S`, both initialized to zero. The array `a` is shared by the two processes. The structures of the processes are shown below.
>
> ```
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> | Process X:              | Process Y:              |
> | private i;              | private i;              |
> | for (i=0; i < n; i++) { | for (i=0; i < n; i++) { |
> |    a[i] = f(i);         |    EntryY(R, S);        |
> |    ExitX(R, S);         |    b[i]=g(a[i]);        |
> | }                       | }                       |
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> ```
>
> How to correctly implement `ExitX()` and `EntryY()`?

**Given solution:**

```
+---------------+----------------+
| ExitX(R, S) { | EntryY(R, S) { |
|   wait(S);    |   signal(S);   |
|   signal(R);  |   wait(R);     |
| }             | }              |
+---------------+----------------+
```

**Question 1 - can we swap wait and signal operations?**

My doubt is will it make difference if we swap these operations, something like below?

```
+---------------+----------------+
| ExitX(R, S) { | EntryY(R, S) { |
|   signal(R);  |   wait(R);     |
|   wait(S);    |   signal(S);   |
| }             | }              |
+---------------+----------------+
```

I believe there is no difference in the behavior and overall outcome of the code when either of above two solutions is used. Am I right?

**Question 2 - is weak alternation even required for this problem?**

I feel the solution above does enforce weak alternation between two processes. That is, at max process X can generate k+2 a's when Y has generated k b's. To produce (k+3)th a, X has to wait for Y to produce (k+1)th b, as during computation of (k+1)th b, Y will signal X, unblocking it. Such weak alternation is not required.

Also I feel we dont really need two semaphores here and one semaphore `T` will suffice. It will be used by X to signal Y when it is blocked, in case there are no further a's produced by X, which can be used by Y to produce b's. Also this will need us to have a variable `m` share by both processes to keep track of difference between a's and b's produced by X and Y as follows:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Process X:              | Process Y:              |
| private i;              | private i;              |
| for (i=0; i < n; i++) { | for (i=0; i < n; i++) { |
|    a[i] = f(i);         |    if(m==0) wait(T);    |
|    m++;                 |    b[i]=g(a[i]);        |
|    if(m==1) signal(T);  |    m--;                 |
| }                       | }                       |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**Question 3**

The text from which I was reading this says having signal() in both EntryY() and ExitX() as a first statement will cause process X to do two signal(R) operation without a wait(R) being done in between by process Y. In given solution, wait() is done twice by process X without letting process Y to do signal() multiple times in between. I believe both have same overall effect of weak alternation as explained in question 2 and none is more preferable than other. Am I correct with this?

Comment: For your question-2 if $m$ has value 1 for instance and then $X$ and $Y$ tries to update it concurrently then $m$ can have incorrect value of $0$ or $1$.

Comment: And there is one more problem. That is let say $X$ runs for one full iteration then it stops(and now $T=1$). Then $Y$ can run for 2 iteration with accessing unproduced item in second iteration(in first iteration not using $wait(T)$ due to $m$ being $1$).